# How to copy a malloced string into another string in C

Tags: c, string, memory, overflow

I have this function that randomly generates a string

```
char *generate_random_string(int seed) {
    if (seed != 0) {
        srand(seed);
    }
    
    char *alpha_num_str =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                "0123456789";
    
    char *random_str = malloc(RAND_STR_LEN);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < RAND_STR_LEN; i++) {
            random_str[i] = alpha_num_str[rand() % (strlen(alpha_num_str) - 1)];
    }
    
    return random_str;
}
```

I want to copy the return value of this function if I give it a seed of '1' into a string called `initialisation_vector` and this is currently how I am doing it:

```
char initialisation_vector[RAND_STR_LEN + 1] = {0};
strcpy(initialisation_vector, generate_random_string(1));
```

However, when I run the code I get a `malloc` buffer overflow error from the `strcpy` line. What am I doing wrong, how do I allocate enough memory for this?

Comment: `strcpy()` wants the source string to be NULL terminated. `malloc()` doesn't do that for you...

Comment: You need to add the zero termination to `random_str` after setting the random characters. To have enough space, you also need to malloc 1 more `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The main issue:**
Strings is C are expected to be [**null/zero terminated**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). This means that an `n` characters string should be allocated with `n+1` bytes and the last one should be `'\0'`.

The problem in your code is that `random_str` is allocated to contain exactly `RAND_STR_LEN` characters and therefore misses the null termination.

**You should change:**

```
char *random_str = malloc(RAND_STR_LEN);
for (int i = 0; i < RAND_STR_LEN; i++) {
    random_str[i] = alpha_num_str[rand() % (strlen(alpha_num_str) - 1)];
}
```

**To:**

```
/*-------------------------------------vvv--*/
char *random_str = malloc(RAND_STR_LEN + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < RAND_STR_LEN; i++) {
    random_str[i] = alpha_num_str[rand() % (strlen(alpha_num_str) - 1)];
}
random_str[RAND_STR_LEN] = '\0';  /* add zero termination */
```

**Note:**
If you want to select random characters from **all** the available ones in `alpha_num_str`, you should use: `rand() % (strlen(alpha_num_str))` (**without the `-1`**). This is because `x % n` will return values of `0..n-1`.
Also for efficiency reasons you can calculate it once before the loop and store in a variable.